# Handling device data using ionic v2 and the BLE Central plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been having some issues with how to best handle the device data of discovered peripherals and wanted to see if anyone can shine some light on this.

I am able to scan for devices perfectly fine, and my "success" callback works as well. What I want to do is create a list that displays the found devices and connects to the one that is selected. I have no problem with creating the list with ng repeat, however I am unsure as to how to proceed with the data that is returned by the success function. How can I go about saving each peripheral into an array so that I can access each individual peripheral's name, id , rssi, etc? I have tried something along the lines of creating an array outside the function to store the peripherals in, and this works perfectly fine inside the starScanning function, however I can't push them into an array from inside the success callback function. If I just store the scan results into an array from inside the startScanning function, is that sufficient?

```
startScanning = function() {

this.ble.startScan([], this.success).subscribe(device => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(device.name));
});
this.isScanning = true;
this.presentLoading();


setTimeout(() => {
  this.ble.stopScan().then(() => {
  console.log("Scanning has stopped");

  this.isScanning = false;
  });
  }, 3000);

 }

success = function(peripheral) {

  console.log("Success Callback called");
  console.log(peripheral.rssi);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle data returned from the scan in the `subscribe` callback (the `startScan` method is supposed to only take an array of services as the parameters according to the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble/):

```
 this.scanSubscription = this.ble.startScan([])
  .subscribe( device => {
    // device will have an id property that you can use to connect
    this.devices.push(device); // devices is an array on your component
  });
```

Now, you can use `*ngFor` to loop over the `devices` array and attach a click handler that passes the device's id:

```
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let device of devices" (click)="connectToDevice(device.id)">{{device.id}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

The `connectToDevice()` takes a device id and connects:

```
connectToDevice(id: string) {
    this.connectSubscription = this.ble.connect(id)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('Successfully connected!');
      });
}
```

A couple of notes:

- It's considered good practice to store subscriptions as properties of your page/component so that you can call `unsubscribe()`on them when a page/component is destroyed to prevent memory leaks
- I'd recommend checking out the `startScanWithOptions` function since you can pass the option `reportDuplicates` with a value of `false` to ignore duplicate devices

Check out my [Github repo](https://github.com/mpedersen15/ionic-bluetooth-demo) (especially the page file `bluetooth.ts`) for a working demo app (this uses the `startScanWithOptions` function I mentioned above, but the functionality is the same)